# c# LINQ query from master and masterdetail table

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, master-detail

I have two tables.

One is `Master`

| Id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-12 |
| 2 | 2022-02-14 |
| 3 | 2021-10-15 |
| 4 | 2021-04-09 |
| 5 | 2020-06-24 |

Another one is `Detail`

| Id | MasterId | Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | item1 | 25 |
| 2 | 1 | item2 | 30 |
| 3 | 1 | item3 | 20 |
| 4 | 2 | item1 | 25 |
| 5 | 2 | item2 | 20 |
| 6 | 3 | item1 | 35 |
| 7 | 4 | item4 | 25 |
| 8 | 5 | item1 | 25 |
| 9 | 5 | item3 | 29 |

From above two table I need a query which will give me 3rd table

| Year | item1 | item2 | item3 | item4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 25 | 0 | 29 | 0 |
| 2021 | 35 | 0 | 0 | 25 |
| 2022 | 50 | 50 | 20 | 0 |

Comment: Add Model classes. LINQ query is build from classes and their properties.

Answer (score 1):

You  want a pivot table

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication18
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            DataTable masterTable = new DataTable("Master");
            masterTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            masterTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

            masterTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, DateTime.Parse("2022-03-12") });
            masterTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, DateTime.Parse("2022-02-14") });
            masterTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, DateTime.Parse("2021-10-15") });
            masterTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, DateTime.Parse("2021-04-09") });
            masterTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, DateTime.Parse("2020-06-24") });

            DataTable detailTable = new DataTable("Detail");
            detailTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            detailTable.Columns.Add("IMasterId", typeof(int));
            detailTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            detailTable.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));

            detailTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1, "item1", 25 });
            detailTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 1, "item2", 30 });
            detailTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, 1, "item3", 20 });
            detailTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, 2, "item1", 25 });
            detailTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, 2, "item2", 20 });
            detailTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, 3, "item1", 35 });
            detailTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 7, 4, "item4", 25 });
            detailTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 8, 5, "item1", 25 });
            detailTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 9, 5, "item3", 29 });

            string[] items = detailTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Name")).OrderBy(x => x).Distinct().ToArray();

            DataTable pivot = new DataTable("Pivot");
            pivot.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(int));
            foreach (string item in items)
            {
                pivot.Columns.Add(item, typeof(int));
            }

            var joinTable = (from m in masterTable.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date"))
                join d in detailTable.AsEnumerable() on m.Field<int>("Id") equals d.Field<int>("Id")
                select new {id = m.Field<int>("Id"), year = m.Field<DateTime>("Date").Year, d = d}
                ).GroupBy(x => x.year).ToList();

            foreach (var date in joinTable)
            {
                DataRow row = pivot.Rows.Add();
                row["Year"] = date.Key;
                var names = date.GroupBy(x => x.d.Field<string>("Name")).Select(x => new {name = x.Key, quant = x.Sum(y => y.d.Field<int>("Quantity"))});
                foreach (var name in names)
                {
                    row[name.name] = name.quant;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```